# Concurrent programming for the novice

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to understand concurrent programming and I'm not sure about one thing. I've got a program that has two threads and they increment the same int (IntCell n). After 200 000 loops the int should have been 400 000, but its a bit over 200 000. And now I wonder if one of the threads is expropriated, when the second one is incrementing it or they just read the same value one after the other, then increment it and set it as int two times (two operations of setting the same int). Here's the code:

```
class IntCell {
    private int n = 0;
    public int getN() {return n;}
    public void setN(int n) {this.n = n;}
}

class Count extends Thread {
    private static IntCell n = new IntCell();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
            temp = n.getN();
            n.setN(temp + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Count p = new Count();
        Count q = new Count();
        p.start();
        q.start();
        try { p.join(); q.join(); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        System.out.println("The value of n is " + n.getN());
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp` is a local variable, each thread will have its own copy of `temp`. There is no chance of any interference.

Comment: @Stultuske Sure, so why don't you delete your comment?

Comment: Because I don't keep a birds-eye on each and every post I commented on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both threads can copy the value of the `static IntCell n` into their thread local storage.

Use the `volatile` keyword to signal the threads to synchronize the thread local value and the shared value.

```
static volatile IntCell n
```

Another problem is failing atomicity, critical region of:

```
// Thread 1    // Thread 2
temp = n.getN();
               temp = n.getN();
               n.setN(temp + 1);
n.setN(temp + 1);
```

With a shared `n` this would increase n not by 2 but just 1.

```
synchronize (n) {
    temp = n.getN();
    n.setN(temp + 1);
}
```

This ensures a *critical region* blocking on a semaphore associated with `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use any kind of [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html), which causes 2 main issues:

1. It is not guaranteed that changes to the shared variable made by one thread are visible to the other
2. There is a race condition between reading the current value of `n` to `temp` and writing the incremented value - the other thread could have modified the value in between, and this would then be overwritten

Possible solutions include using `synchronized`-blocks, the locks in the packet [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) or types that support atomic updates, such as [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)